# UIAlertController Action not showing UIView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

The progress dialog just doesn't want to show, its like its hidden, or something. Please see steps taken and example code.

I have the following steps

1. Modal shown (list of data)
2. UIAlertController is shown (password expired, needs to reenter password)
3. Progress bar over lay show (UIView)
4. Service call runs, until completed
5. Dismiss progress bar

UIAlertController

```
private void ShowLogin(string message, Action<ExpiredResponseTypes> responseHandler)
{
     UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
     {
         var loginAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("Enter password", "", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

         //add login text
         {basic normal code}

         loginAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
          (actionHandler) =>
          {
              ShowProgress();
              var loginResult = HandleLogin();
              DismissProgress();
              loginResponseHandler(loginResult);
          }));
          AlertAutoLayoutHelper.TopLevelViewController().PresentViewController(loginAlertController, true, null);
   });
}
```

AlertAutoLayoutHelper.TopLevelViewController

```
public static UIViewController TopLevelViewController()
    {
        var window = new UIWindow(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Frame);
        var vc = new UIViewController();
        vc.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        window.RootViewController = vc;
        window.WindowLevel = UIWindowLevel.Alert + 1;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
        return vc;
    }
```

ShowProgress

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    var bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
    loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay(bounds, optionalMessage, isSpecificLoader);

      if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.ModalViewController != null)
      {
         UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.ModalViewController.View.AddSubview(loadingOverlay);
      }
      else
      { UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View.AddSubview(loadingOverlay);
      }

         isProgressShowing = true;
 });
```

Overlay

```
 public class LoadingOverlay : UIView
    {
        UIActivityIndicatorView activitySpinner;
        UILabel loadingLabel;

        public LoadingOverlay(CGRect frame, string message = null, bool isSpecificLoader = false) : base(frame)
        {
            {just normal setup }
            AddSubview(activitySpinner);
            AddSubview(loadingLabel);
        }
    }
```

Note: progress dialog works fine for normal situations, showing when called from UIViewController)

I've been stuck for days, please assist.

Comment: Could you please provide an basic demo that can reproduce the issue, so that I can test it by my side.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT thank you for being willing to help. I have a deadline that pop up for Friday, but will try create and get an example project to you asap